# Js file throwing an error after .net framework upgraded to 6.0

Tags: javascript, .net-core, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-2.1, devextreme

Old Framework -> .net core 2.2
upgraded framework -> .net 6.0
Deployed application to IIS 10
Error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined(reading 'toLowerCase')
Error->
[image]

Dev extreme version -> 20.2.6
Any idea why how to solve this issue? This internal.js is a custom js.
I have 2 web apps in IIS for the same application.
Web app with .net framework core 2.2 -> working fine without error
Web app with .net framework 6.0 -> giving this error in js

Comment: Find the statement, console.log the string you are trying to run toLowerCase on, it is probably null or a number or you forgot the () on toLowerCase()

Comment: @mplungjan..As i mentioned i have two instance of this application pointing to same db. I mean i had hosted two times this same application in IIS one with .net core framework 2.2 and another is the upgraded version of this same application with .net framework 6.0 pointing to same db. App with 2.2 is working without issue but app with 6.0 is throwing an error

Comment: @mplungjan ....In response section i can see the data from the api call

Comment: I understand, but what does a console.log tell you on the alleged string you try to lowerCase?

Answer (score 2):

This issue is resolved. .net 6.0 framework convert the uppercase column names return from api to camelcase because of this javascript was not able to get the desired column name and throwing the null error.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-7-0

Comment: Hey, I am facing the same issue after the upgrade. Did you have to change any settings or do something else to get it to work?

Comment: @The_Outsider..you can make small change in your model class like this. [JsonProperty("access_token")]
public string AccessToken { get